# Accidentally zeroed first 20GB of 2.73TB ext4 partition. Any way to recover the rest?

Tags: data-recovery

I accidentally repartitioned a wrong hard drive and seems like the first 20GB of the 2.7TB disk was lost (some belonging to old partition).

If I examine the disk with (new partition sdd1 starts after 20GB):

> dd if=/dev/sdd1 count=1000000 | strings | sed -nr '/^.{8,149}$/p'

I will see some contents of my old files, but nothing on the first 20GB of /dev/sdd.

Is there some way to recover the files that exist in the hard drive after the first 20GB?

Comment: You can use PhotoRec to recover files from the raw data on a drive. See [this link](https://www.cgsecurity.org).

Comment: @sudodus: Seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that it works, but I'm afraid that you have a lot of hard manual work to organize the files again, because I think the file names and the directories are probably lost. Good luck :-)